# MySQL data integer to SQL Server datetime type

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data exported from MySQL db to XLS file.
There is Date column with integers (like below).
I want to convert the integers to SQL Server datetime type.

```
DateColumn
66478 
69035 
66478 
69400 
...
```

Maybe someone know how to convert it to SQL Server datetime format?

Comment: `66478` does not look like a valid date in mysql either, and so as the given list.

Comment: What dates does this numbers represent?

Comment: Problem is that i don't know. I don't have access to MySQL DB and never seen how it looks like in original. Probably someone who delivered the data and prepare the export made something wrong.

Comment: Is it possible the numbers are the days since 1900 (after convert on excel) - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252?

Answer (score 0):

Since the integer values from excel are coming from a date column on MySQL, I assume these integer values are the days since 1900-01-01. A date on excel is stored as integer / sequence number:

> Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can be used in calculations. By default, January 1, 1900 is serial number 1, and January 1, 2008 is serial number 39448 because it is 39,447 days after January 1, 1900.
>   **source:** https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252

So you can use the following query to get the date from integer values on sql server:

```
SELECT DATEADD(D, int_column - 1, '19000101')

-- example
SELECT DATEADD(D, 66478 - 1, '19000101') -- 2082-01-03
```